# How to save chart from excel as image/PDF?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I want to **extract/read** a chart (Bar graph/ Pie chart etc.) from my `.xlsx` file using `Apache POI and Java` and **save it as an image or as a PDF** on my hard drive.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I export charts from Excel as graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495480/how-do-i-export-charts-from-excel-as-graphics)

Comment: I do not want to use Aspose as it is not free. About JExcel, I can see it is not recommended to use instead of Apache POI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much investigation, apparently I can see that it is **not possible** to extract charts from Excel using Apache POI and save it as an image or as a PDF.

The approach one can take in this situation is to use COM based solution using **Com4j** (http://com4j.kohsuke.org/) to convert **Excel to PDF** and then use **Apache PDFBox** (https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to convert from **PDF to Image**.

---

Giving below brief details about how to use Com4j to convert **Excel into PDF** programmatically:

1. Generate Java classes artifacts from Excel with following command:

   > java -jar tlbimp-2.1.jar -o wsh -p com.mycompany.excel4j "C:\Program
   >   Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe"

   We need 3 JARs for above conversion: *com4j-2.1.jar*, *tlbimp-2.1.jar*, *args4j-2.0.8.jar*

   We may download corresponding JARs from - http://com4j.kohsuke.org/maven-com4j-plugin/dependencies.html

   For more information, refer: http://com4j.kohsuke.org/
2. Copy generated Java artifacts into your workspace or create a JAR of these and use after adding it into application classpath.
3. Use following snippet to invoke generated COM APIs from Java and convert first sheet of specified Excel file to PDF (Replace accordingly on your computer the paths mentioned in the following snippet for Excel and PDF files):

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       _Application excelApplication = ClassFactory.createApplication();

   _Workbook workbook = excelApplication
           .workbooks()
           .open("C:\\Users\\Akki\\Desktop\\MyExcel.xlsx",
                   null, null, null, null,
                   null, null, null,
                   null, null, null, null, null,
                   null, null, 0);

   workbook.exportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "C:\\Users\\Akki\\Desktop\\MyPDF.pdf", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

   workbook.close(false, null,null, 0);

   excelApplication.quit();

   System.out.println("Converted Excel to PDF!"); }
   ```

Cheers,

Akshay